# Rewriting an expression until no other logarithm properties can be applied:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\log_{a}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{m^8 n^12}{a^3 b^5}}}$

Log has a base of a and the square root is 4 sqrt. I couldn't format it. I am new.
 - For My final answer I ended up with: $2\log_{a}{m} + 2\log_{a}{n}-\frac{\text{3}}{\text{4}}-\frac{5}{4}\log_{a}{b}$ 
 Is this correct? - Thank you 
- NOTE: The base for this problem is a. I couldn't format it correctly. Does anyone know a good place to find all the markdowns for MathOverflow? I went to advanced help, but nothing really helped for the math portion. - Than you

Comment: try to write equation(s) in http://www.hostmath.com

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot.

Comment: Would you be able to check if my answer is correct? - Thank you

Comment: your simplification is true